# Flask-restful basic Authentication

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am new to Flask and I need some help for my school work.

I am trying to build a simple ToDo list system using flask-restful.

My current code looks like this:

```
class ToDoList(Resource):
    '''TODO LIST'''
    operation = ['delete']
    decorators = [auth.login_required, advertise('operation')]
    def post(self):
        """remove all item in the TODO list"""
        operation = request.args.get('op')
        if operation == 'delete':
            collection2.delete_many({})
            return {'Success': 'OK'}, 200
        return {'Error':'Illegal Operation'}, 400
    def get(self):
        """return a list of the TODO name"""
        list_1 = collection2.find()
        list_2 = []
        for each in list_1:
            list_2.append(JSONEncoder().encode(each))
        return {'list':list_2}, 200
```

It works, but I want only the `post` method to require authentication, and `get` method without authentication so anyone can acquire the list without login. I am using the flask-restful I don't know how to give the decorators separately to each function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Flask-RESTful documentation [[1](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#resource-method-decorators)]:

> Alternatively, you can specify a dictionary of iterables that map to HTTP methods and the decorators will only apply to matching requests.

```
def cache(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def cacher(*args, **kwargs):
        # caching stuff
    return cacher

class MyResource(restful.Resource):
     method_decorators = {'get': [cache]}

     def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return something_interesting(*args, **kwargs)

     def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return create_something(*args, **kwargs)
```

In your case it would be:

```
method_decorators = {'post': [auth.login_required]}
```

Answer (score 5):

I used flaskrestplus to do basic authentication. All the required authorizations are provided as an authorizations dictionary. Then they are passed to the API.
Also the authorizations can be applied at the method level using

```
@api.doc(security='basicAuth')
```

The validation logic (can be ldap validation or db validation) can be writted in a decorator called requires_Auth. This decorator is invoked using

```
decorators = [requires_Auth]
```

Complete code

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource
from functools import wraps

def requires_Auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if auth:
           print "inside decorator", auth.username,auth.password
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return "Login required!!!!",401
    return decorator


authorizations = {
    'basicAuth': {
        'type': 'basic',
        'in': 'header',
        'name': 'Authorization'
    }
}
api = Api(app, version='1.0', 
    authorizations=authorizations
)

ns = api.namespace('/', description='Authentication API')

@ns.route('/withDecorator')
class HelloWorldWithDecorator(Resource):
    decorators = [requires_Auth]
    @api.doc(security='basicAuth')
    def get(self):        
        return {'hello': 'world'}

api.add_namespace(ns)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```